# Multi tables has a relationship to the same table

Tags: sql

I'm building a simple website to save everything I learn in Japanese (personal hobby ^^).

I'm having a few table, say `kanjis` (which list all the kanjis in lessons), `grammars`, `new_words` . etc . With each type of list like that , I'd like to have one or more sample sentences for each item (example sentences for each kanji letter, each new grammar or new words ...)

So my question here is: should I have seperate `example_sentences` tables for each type of item above, or I can share 1 `example_sentences` with all `kanjis`,`new_grammars`, `new_words` .etc.

Another question here is: in case I want 1 `sample_sentences` can be reuse (say, 1 sentences can be linked to more than 1 new word, or 1 new word and 1 grammar note .etc.) In this case - with a many-to-many - relationship , do I still only need 1 generic `sample_sentences` and then have a `join_table` for each type of `kanjis`,`new_words`,`grammars`...

I draw an image for the second question here (sorry, I draw it with paint.)

[image]

Comment: At the office, can't see the image. I have edited my answer to add a many-to-many proposal, check that and see if it can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "material" stored for your examples will always be a sentence, thus it is the same material, thus you need only one table.

---

In a One to many relationship, your first question, thats simple. 
Just one `example` table with a column to know from which orig table it comes.

```
ID | Orig     | OrigID |   Sentence
----------------------------------------------
1  | Kanji    | 1      | whatever   
2  | grammars | 1      | whatever
3  | Kanji    | 2      | whatever   
4  | Kanji    | 3      | whatever
5  | grammars | 2      | whatever           
6  | new_words| 1      | whatever
```

---

In a many-to-many relationship, your second question, that's a bit more complicated

The `example` table would be :

```
ID |   Sentence                   
--------------------------        
1  | whatever                     
2  | whatever                     
3  | whatever                     
4  | whatever                     
5  | whatever                     
6  | whatever
```

And the `Many-to-Many` table would be:

```
ID | ExampleID| OrigID| Orig     |
----------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1     | Kanji    |
2  | 1        | 1     | grammars |
3  | 2        | 2     | Kanji    |
4  | 3        | 3     | Kanji    |
5  | 2        | 2     | grammars |
6  | 6        | 1     | new_words|
```

And you would need to query this table mostly all the time with a combination of  `Orig + OrigID`

Answer (score 0):

An example sentence is an entity and should have its own table.  And example sentence will likely have multiple "new words" as well as multiple "Grammars"  Therefore you would want a M-to-M relationship between Example Sentences and Grammars and you would want a different M-to-M relationship between Example Sentences and New Words.